# Android - Cannot change textcolor from xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-styles

I'm stuck with a very strange issue. 
I can't change the TextColor of some TextViews around the app, neither with the `android:textColor=""` nor by setting a *style*. It only works if I change it at *runtime*. 
This problem appeared without any change related to the activity in question. The most strange thing is that in the *Preview* the colors are fine, but when I run it, the colors are always the same.
What might be overriding the textColor value set in the XML ?
**Thx Anticipately**

P.S:
Along all the App I can only change the color of the textHint

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove all the N preview stuff from my sdk to make things normal again. Don't forget the cache too.

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design|support-v-13|ect./24~
```

Comment: You saved me from becoming crazy, Thx Man !
However I didn't delete the files in the folder, I just changed the compile dependencies in gradle and everything's fine now

Comment: AAla :) i just changed the dependencies and sdk version and it works

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of xml line you wrote  is wrong

instead of

`android:setTextColor=""`

use

```
android:textColor=""
```

Comment: Then add the xml code not enough information is provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Text Color in layout XML by using android:textColor

example:

```
  android:textColor="#0E0E9A"
```

it overrides the style.xml

the only way to override your layout.xml is by code

example:

```
 mEditText.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing ! And this problem is driving me crazy !
I'm not changing the color at runtime and I'm only setting it in the xml with textColor